# Understanding the behavior of the variable in a query

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I need know the behavior of the variable `user`.
The code below works well:

```
var user = await Usuario.findOne({
            where:{username:usuario_email}
        }); 
        if(!user){
            retorno.excecao(res, null, { mensagem: "not found" });
            return;
        }
```

But, when i use `findAll` the statment if dont work, neither the opposite(user == true):

```
var user = await Usuario.findAll({
            where: {[Op.or]: [{email: usuario_email}, {username: usuario_email}]}
            //where:{username:usuario_email}
        }); 
        if(!user){ //neither if(user) works
            retorno.excecao(res, null, { mensagem: "not found" });
            return;
        }
```

Why?

Sorry for my bad english or bilingual sections.

Answer (score 1):

The function `findAll()` will still return an array even if the result of the query is empty - so the variable `user` will be an empty array `[]`.

An empty array is still truthy so your `if` statement won't work. Instead, check the length of the array.

```
if (user.length === 0) {
    // the query returned empty
}
```

Comment: that's weird,i tested and both conditions resulting array.length > 0